# JavaScript form validation in jQuery Mobile

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mobile

I am doing a mobile version  of an existing site . I have included mobile css and jquery's for some special effects. but i have done validation using javascipt. When i have checked validation it works properly in ipad, mobile, and in my pc also.But  after 2 ,3 weeks  when i checked the site again it won't works. I have created a demo which also doesn't work:

http://jsfiddle.net/dPes7/27/

Comment: The problem with your fiddle was that you did not select "no-wrap" which is necessary to create global functions - but obviously it would be better to not use inline events calling global functions at all.

Comment: @ThiefMaster  sorry i didn't get you, can you explain  it clearly

Comment: the example throws an error telling `Uncaught ReferenceError: hide_text is not defined` add the function to see what's wrong with your code

Comment: @jorge the fiddle works fine but in ipad and mobiles it won't works. I have tried to alert values but the page refresh, in desktop it works fine.Could you please tell me why this happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rewrite and start over. Your JS is messed up. Here's an example to go from: http://www.elijahmanor.com/2011/02/jquery-mobile-form-validation.html

Includes a working JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a doc ready?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('form[name=YourForm]').submit(check);
})
```

I typically don't do data-role="none" for submit buttons.

Comment: You don't use document ready in jquery mobile to trigger functions. Important: Use $(document).bind('pageinit'), not $(document).ready() See here:http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html